# To many items for Excel drop down list when using validation.add from c#

Tags: c#, excel, validation, vsto

In my c# project, which creates xlsx file, there is a rows in code, which deletes and then sets validation for a range of cells:

```
VedomostSheet.Range[VedomostSheet.Cells[VedomostStartRow, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 1, DicSheet))], VedomostSheet.Cells[20000, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 1, DicSheet))]].Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, values, Type.Missing);
```

For this row of code debugger throws an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException HResult=0x800A03EC
> Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Source= Cannot evaluate the
> exception source StackTrace: Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace

As I found out this is because there are too many values for a drop down list, which are stored in values variable of Validation.Add() function.

How can I overcome the limit on the number of values for a drop-down list when adding validation?

Comment: Put the data in a range (1 row or column), and use the address of that range as the DV source.

Comment: @Rory, that is I need to insert this range instead of my _values_ variable in example above? I was trying to find the documentation about Validation method but I didn't find it... :)

Comment: Yes - use the **address** of the range in place of `values`

Comment: @Rory, here is the code  `myrange = DicSheet.Range[DicSheet.Cells[2, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 2, DicSheet))], DicSheet.Cells[row-1, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 2, DicSheet))]];VedomostSheet.Range[VedomostSheet.Cells[VedomostStartRow, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 1, DicSheet))], VedomostSheet.Cells[20000, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 1, DicSheet))]].Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, myrange.Address, Type.Missing);`

Comment: And after that I see the value like $J$2:$J$315 in a drop down list. Sorry, I don't know how to add new line in a comments to display two rows of code above

Comment: You need to prefix it with an `=` sign and include the sheet name.

Comment: @Rory, I don't understand. Can you supply an example based on my code?

Comment: Instead of just `myrange.Address`, use `"='" & myrange.worksheet.name & "'!" & myrange.address` or whatever the C# equivalent to that is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution(thanks to @Rory):

```
Range myrange;//creating the range variable with all values for drop down list
myrange = DicSheet.Range[DicSheet.Cells[2, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 2, DicSheet))], DicSheet.Cells[row-1, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 2, DicSheet))]];
//using this variable with the name of a excel sheet:
VedomostSheet.Range[VedomostSheet.Cells[VedomostStartRow, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 1, DicSheet))], VedomostSheet.Cells[20000, Convert.ToInt16(GetCellValue(rowDic, 1, DicSheet))]].Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, "='" + DicSheet.Name + "'!" + myrange.Address, Type.Missing);
```